# “Server error: this file/item may not be moved, deleted, renamed or otherwise edited” - What Should I do in my case?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I wish to delete some .html and .master files and im using Sharepoint Designer. However I have this error:

> Server error: this file may not be moved, deleted, renamed or otherwise edited.

or

> Server error: this item cannot be deleted because it is still referenced by other pages.

[image]

I tried:

- https://www.techmikael.com/2013/02/issue-with-creating-copy-of.html
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother-msoversion_other/unable-to-delete-sharepoint-2013-masterpage-from/db153743-6370-4468-a572-8a11c5c900be

I'm also using "Seattle" and the files bellow are copies from "Seattle":

- test.html
- startermaster_copy(2).html
- startermaster_copy(1).html
- starter.html

I'm out of options.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the same from the browser. Refer below url to go to master page gallery:

```
/_catalogs/masterpage
```

Comment: didn't work. I tried to delete one by one.

Comment: Did you get any error when you tried to delete using browser?

Comment: Error when deleting "The server has encountered the following error(s):
startermaster.html
This file may not be moved, deleted, renamed, or otherwise edited."

or 

"The server has encountered the following error(s):
test.master
This item cannot be deleted because it is still referenced by other pages."

Comment: @SaulKevinSilva So you deleted all the html files one by one and so it resolved?

Comment: No sorry, I explained It wrong. What I was trying to say is that I can't delete html files with your solutions via web.

Comment: @SaulKevinSilva Did you get any error when you tried to delete using browser?

Comment: Yes, this errors below:

"The server has encountered the following error(s): startermaster.html This file may not be moved, deleted, renamed, or otherwise edited." or "The server has encountered the following error(s): test.master This item cannot be deleted because it is still referenced by other pages."

Comment: @SaulKevinSilva So how did you solve it?

Comment: I can't Solve it. That's why It gives me errors. I Just want to delete that files and I can't delete them from browser and SPD.

Comment: @SaulKevinSilva The master page that you're trying to delete might be the default master page set for that site.

Comment: My default Master Page is "Seattle".
If I go to "_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx" my Site Master Page and System Master Page are both with "Seattle".